# I discovered that $\int\frac1{x^2+1}dx\equiv\arctan x$ and can be used to calculate $\pi$ as well as several trig functions within a domain.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm not sure how this works, but I've found out that $\int\frac1{x^2+1}dx\equiv\arctan x$, which can be used to calculate $\pi$ by plugging in 1 and multiplying by 4, as well as most trigonometric functions that have the domain of $-\frac\pi2<x<\frac\pi2$ (which can be solved by simply repeating the function over all real numbers) eg. $$\text{Let }f(x)=\int\frac1{x^2+1}dx\\\frac1{\frac d{dx}f^{-1}(x)}\equiv\left\{-\frac\pi2<x<\frac\pi2\ \middle|\ \cos^2x\right\}$$
When I first discovered this, I was completely shocked, and I haven't been able to find any documentation about this. I'd like to know how any of this works and how the reciprocal of a simple parabola calculates trigonometric functions and $\pi$.

Comment: $\arctan(1)=\pi /4$, is that what you mean?

Comment: moreover, $\int \frac1{1+x^2} \mathrm dx= \arctan(x)+c$

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = \int_0^1 [1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \cdots - \cdots] \,dx.$$  This equals $$\int_0^1 1\,dx - \int_0^1 x^2\,dx + \int_0^1 x^4 \,dx - \int_0^1 x^6 \,dx + \cdots - \cdots.$$  This allows you to conclude that $$\frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \cdots - \cdots .$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{d [ ~\text{arctan}(x) ~]}{dx} = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}~$ is a standard result that I would expect to be found in any college course on Real Analysis.

Comment: "When I first discovered this, I was completely shocked". Really? Why? It is what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the value of $\pi$ can be calculated from this integral, although the process you described in your question is not entirely clear. It is true that

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+1} \: \mathrm{d}x = \arctan(x) + C$$ for an arbitrary [constant of integration](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConstantofIntegration.html) $C$, but you can't just "plug in 1" as you describe above into the integrand (the function you are integrating). To derive an integral expression of $\pi$, a [*definite integral*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DefiniteIntegral.html) (with limits of integration) is necessary; what I've written above is an [*indefinite integral*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteIntegral.html) with no limits of integration.

By the [Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html), the integral from $0$ to some value $s$ of the above integral expression is (given that $\arctan(0) = 0$):

$$\int_{0}^{s} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \: \mathrm{d}x = \arctan(s) - \arctan(0) = \arctan(s).$$

Since $\arctan(1) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$, this implies that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \: \mathrm{d}x = \arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Therefore:

$$\boxed{\pi = 4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \: \mathrm{d}x}. $$

*Try inputting the right-hand side of the equation into calculators such as [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=4Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2B1%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) -- you will get $\pi$* :)

---

To consider why the arc tangent function is related to this integral involving the reciprocal of a "simple parabola," recall the Pythagorean trigonometric identities:

\begin{aligned}
\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1 \\
1 + \tan^2(\theta) = \sec^2(\theta) \\
1 + \cot^2(\theta) = \csc^2(\theta) \\
\end{aligned}

The second identity, $1 + \tan^2(\theta) = \sec^2(\theta)$, is the most useful in the case of arc tangent. As B. Goddard demonstrated, these trigonometric identities can be used to our advantage to solve the integral (using a method known as trigonometric substitution).

In the case of arc tangent, $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \: \mathrm{d}x$ can be simplified with the substitution $x = \tan(\theta), \mathrm{d}x = \sec^2(\theta) \: \mathrm{d}\theta$ (remember your [trigonometric derivatives](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/03%3A_Derivatives/3.05%3A_Derivatives_of_Trigonometric_Functions)!):

\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \: \mathrm{d}x &= \int \frac{1}{\tan^2(\theta) + 1} (\sec^2(\theta) \: \mathrm{d}\theta) \\
&= \int \frac{1}{\sec^2(\theta)}(\sec^2(\theta) \: \mathrm{d}\theta) \\ 
&= \int \frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{\sec^2(\theta)} \: \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \int \: \mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{aligned}

With $\displaystyle \int \: \mathrm{d}\theta = \theta + C$ and $\theta = \arctan(x)$ (since $x = \tan(\theta)$; solve for $\theta$), we are done.

As for the remainder of the trigonometric and inverse (arc) trigonometric functions (which have similar patterns), they will be listed in most calculus textbooks and integral tables. [Here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Differential_Calculus/Differential_Calculus_(Seeburger)/Derivatives_of_the_Inverse_Trigonometric_Functions) is a thorough walk-through in determining the derivative of each inverse trigonometric function; taking the integral of the result with respect to $x$ will undo this process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to see the relationship, let $u = \arctan(x)$, so that $x=\tan u$. Then your integral looks like

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\tan^2u} \; dx = u+c.$$

(I've deliberately left the $dx$ in.)  But $dx = \sec^2 u \; du$, and $1+\tan^2 u = \sec^2u$, so the equation becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{\sec^2 u} \sec^2 u \; du = u+c$$

or

$$\int du = u + c.$$

Trig functions, if you look at their Taylor series, are nearly polynomials, so it's not really so much of a stretch that these (barely) transcendental functions interact nicely with bona fide polynomials.